# Exception in copying DataRow to another DataTable

Tags: c#

I have two data tables, dt1 & dt2. dt1 has data while dt2 is a new table. Now I want to copy some rows, satisfying particular condition, to dt2. I have tried following code, but I get this exception:

> System.ArgumentException This row already belongs to another table.

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
{
   if(Convert.ToInt32(dr["col"]) == value)
   {
      dt2.Rows.Add(dr);
   }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change  `dt2.Rows.Add(dr);` to  `dt2.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);`

Answer (score 0):

You directly cannot `"Add"` a DataTable row from one to another since it belongs to souce Datatable. You can `"Add"` a newly created row to DataTable.

Hence you are getting this exception.

There are many ways to overcome this. Some are listed below

**Method 1:**

If you want to get a row from source Datatable and add in destination without any changes, then use `ImportRow` this way.

```
dt2.ImportRow(dr);
```

**Method 2:**

But if you want to take specific data. Then use this

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
{
   if(Convert.ToInt32(dr["col"]) == value)
   {
      Datarow ndr = dt2.NewRow();
      ndr["Foo"] = dr["Foo"];
      //..Similarly for other rows.
      dt2.Rows.Add(ndr);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you add a row to the datatable it should be different(new) row........

```
Datarow newRow = null;
foreach(DataRow dr in dt1.Rows)
{
  if(Convert.ToInt32(dr["col"]) == value)
  {
   newRow = dt2.NewRow();
   newRow ["A"] = dr["A"];     
   dt2.Rows.Add(newRow );
  }
 }
```